# Exporting some table table from Oracle DB to MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, oracle

I need to export some of the tables from Oracle DB to Mysql DB. I don't have any previous experience of export and import. Could someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried looking for available information on what may be needed to establish connection between these two platforms, as well as following the found instructions?

Comment: I exported the tables by creating Sql file and running that in mysql..Now what i need is datasync

Answer (score 3):

Oracle export tools use their own proprietary format that MySQL can not process.

Just unload your data to CSV or insert statements with SQL Developer, then load the result in MySQL

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168398/how-to-export-query-result-to-csv-in-oracle-sql-developer

Comment: thank you for your answer. Now that part is done. but when those tables in Oracle got updated it should be reflected in Mysql too..how do i do that?

Comment: i did the export by generating sql script and ran the same in Mysql DB after making necessary changes to the datatypes

Answer (score 1):

My [open-source](https://github.com/calmitchell617/sqlpipe) product [SQLpipe](https://sqlpipe.com) is able to transfer data from Oracle to MySQL. It can even handle non-human readable formats like binary blobs.

I wrote this guide on using SQLpipe to [transfer data from Oracle to MySQL](https://sqlpipe.com/transfer-data-from-oracle-to-mysql/).

The basic steps are:

1. Install SQLpipe (it is just a CLI binary, with no dependencies)
2. Run a command like this one:

```
sqlpipe transfer \
  --source-ds-type "oracle" \
  --source-hostname "your-oracle-hostname" \
  --source-port 1521 \
  --source-db-name "your-oracle-db-name" \
  --source-username "your-oracle-username" \
  --source-password "your-oracle-password"
  --target-ds-type "mysql" \
  --target-hostname "your-mysql-hostname" \
  --target-port 3306 \
  --target-db-name "your-mysql-db-name" \
  --target-username "your-mysql-username" \
  --target-password "your-mysql-password" \
  --target-table "name-of-table-to-insert-into" \
  --overwrite \
  --query "select * from table_name_to_move"
```

Note that the query can be arbitrary - so you can exclude certain columns from being transferred.